# VS code debugger could not find pdb of nuget package and does not enter code in debug

Tags: c#, vscode-debugger, .net-7.0

I'm using vs code 1.83.1, net7.0 (7.0.400).

I try to debug a external nuget package Project.X.dll (compile with .net standard 2.0) by running unit test of another project Client.Project.Tests that reference it but vscode debuguer does not step into the code and i can't debug.

The debuguer try to open the code and show the message "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found." because it's tried to open the code build by the CI server in a specific path and it's not existing locally.

I'm using nunit for unit test framework and the project is build with .net 7.

In the debug console i can see that the pdb cannot be find by the debugger for the Dll.X.dll.

'..\Project\bin\Debug\net7.0\Project.X.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

But, i have another dll that work the same and symbols are loaded and i can debug this one.

'..\Project\bin\Debug\net7.0\Project.Y.dll'. Symbols loaded.

I can't figure why the pdb can't be loaded and i also have tried to just put the pdb in the output folder without success.

I have tried to set thoses 3 parameters in settings and in the local launch.json file but it's not working.

"suppressJITOptimizations": true,
"justMyCode": false
"requireExactSource": false

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {      
          "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
          "type": "coreclr",
          "request": "launch",
          "preLaunchTask": "build","${workspaceFolder}/src/Client.Project.Tests/bin/Debug/net7.0/Client.Project.Tests.dll",
          "args":[ "${relativeFile}"],
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Client.Project.Tests",
          "console": "internalConsole",
          "stopAtEntry": true,
          "justMyCode": false,
          "suppressJITOptimizations": true,
          "requireExactSource": false
      },
      {
          "name": ".NET Core Attach",
          "type": "coreclr",
          "request": "attach",
          "suppressJITOptimizations": true,
          "justMyCode": false
      }
  ]
}
```